# How do I search for recently well-received questions?

Tags: support, search

Basically what's in the title. To clarify, the problem with the `votes` tab is that it gets you extremely high-voted, and extremely ancient questions. I just want to look for recently asked questions that have a good amount of upvotes. Sort of like a clash of the `votes` and `active` tabs.

Is this possible?

Comment: Search for something like [`is:q created:2015-04-01..`](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aq%20created%3a2015-04-01..). See also the [help centre](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/searching) for searching methods.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks much!

Comment: @Daniel: That's odd, you're American and the site is American, and yet you wrote "centre". :-)

Comment: If you go to the main page, math.stackexchange.com, in the centre of the page there should be a set of 'tabs' that read `active` `featured` `hot` `week` `month`. The `week` and `month` tabs should also roughly satisfy your desire. I have no idea what it takes to be included in those, or the `hot` tab, but they're usually the better received questions of the last time period.

Comment: @asaf, if i type center it puts a wiggly underline that says the spelling is incorrect. On Facebook with Old John, I use Britishisms; it turns out that tosser and wanker are approximately equal, while pillock is milder.

Comment: @Asaf What gave you the idea I were American? I'm European as far as I know.

Comment: @Daniel: That's odd. Can you check again maybe? :-)